# Elixir: Counting Frequency of Words in Text File in Hangul Alphabet

Tags: utf-8, elixir

But I am working with some data written in Hangul. I have a word frequency script that I have used for English txt files, but the script fails when I pass a UTF-8 txt file containing Hangul characters. Specifically, it seems to read basically all the characters as blank spaces. This is the results, stored in a .csv file:

```
, 290668
1, 2
2, 5
3d, 1
4, 1
55, 1
6, 1
6mm, 2
709, 2
710, 1
d, 1
j, 87
k, 1
m, 14
p, 19
pd100, 1
y, 1
```

Considering the text in the file contains none of these characters, this seems to be a problem. So how do I make my code read hangul? This is my current code:

```
defmodule WordFrequency do

  def wordCount(readFile) do
     readFile
     |> words
     |> count
     |> tocsv
  end

  defp words(file) do
    file
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing(&1))
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1,~r{[^A-Za-z0-9_]}))
    |> Enum.to_list
    |> List.flatten
    |> Enum.map(&String.downcase(&1))
  end

  defp count(words) when is_list(words) do
    Enum.reduce(words, %{}, &update_count/2)
  end

  defp update_count(word, acc) do
    Map.update acc, String.to_atom(word), 1, &(&1 + 1)
  end

  defp tocsv(map) do
    File.open("wordfreqKor.csv", [:write, :utf8], fn(file) ->
      Enum.each(map, &IO.write(file, Enum.join(Tuple.to_list(&1), ", ")<>"\n"))
    end)
  end

end

WordFrequency.wordCount("myfile.txt")
```

Thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: Since you haven't provided the actual input, I can only guess, but it looks like the problem is the regex you're splitting over. Try splitting with `~r/\s+/` instead.